# css property float left is not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS. Here is my problem.

[image]

**The Code:**

```css
.floatleft {float: left}
.floatright {float: right}
.colum{width: 1170px; margin: 0 auto;}
.fix {overflow: hidden}
.clear {clear: both}
```

```html
<div class="services_area">
  <div class="colum">
    <div class="services">
      <div class="services_title fix">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <span>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</span> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services_list">
      <div class="ss_list floatleft">
        <img src="img/bulb.png" alt="">
        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ss_list floatleft">
        <img src="img/pen.png" alt="">
        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ss_list floatleft">
        <img src="img/settings.png" alt="">
        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ss_list floatleft">
        <img src="img/desktop.png" alt="">
        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is no more code. First time I want to just float left, then that thing happened.

What is the error here? What should I do now?

Comment: you should use clear:both.

Comment: you dont have class of `.floatleft`. But you have `.floatright` to float left.

Comment: `.floatright` to `.floatleft`?

Comment: double check the class you have applied and created in CSS.

Comment: I have .floatleft too but there was mistake.

Comment: You have not provided full code of your styelsheet. Code for floatleft ,service_title, ss_list is not here. Edit your question and put complete code.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the top of your code.
`floatright {float: left}` <== It looks like you set the wrong `float` on the wrong **class**.

Comment: I changed that and also clearing both. now its work.

Answer (score 2):

```
You have mistaken as .floatright to be change as .floatleft in your style
```

```css
.floatleft {float: left}
.colum{width: 1170px; margin: 0 auto;}
.fix {overflow: hidden}
```

```html
<div class="services_area">
            <div class="colum">
                <div class="services">
                    <div class="services_title fix">
                        <h1>About Me</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <span>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</span> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="services_list">
                    <div class="ss_list floatleft">
                        <img src="img/bulb.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ss_list floatleft">
                        <img src="img/pen.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ss_list floatleft">
                        <img src="img/settings.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ss_list floatleft">
                        <img src="img/desktop.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `.floatleft{float: left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. now working good. This is great. All of you are great. I love the stackoverflow. how speedy reply here!!!

```css
.floatleft {float: left}
.floatright {float: right}
.colum{width: 1170px; margin: 0 auto;}
.fix {overflow: hidden}
.clear {clear: both}
```